# Java implementation of Quicksort with Arraylist Troubleshooting

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, arraylist, quicksort

I'm trying to implement the quicksort algorithm with ArrayList but can't seem to get this working. It gives me an error for my recursive return call in the sort() function. Please help!

This is the error I get: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    l.add(10); l.add(7); l.add(13); l.add(22); l.add(9);
    //l.get(2);


    System.out.println(sort(l));


}


public static List<Integer> sort(List<Integer> l) {

    if (l.size() <= 1) {
        return l;
    }

    int pivot = l.get(0);
    List<Integer> left = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> right = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
        if (l.get(i) < pivot) {
            left.add(l.get(i));
            //System.out.println(left);
        } else {
            right.add(l.get(i));
        }

    }
    return join(sort(left), sort(right), pivot);
}

public static List<Integer> join(List<Integer> left, List<Integer> right, int pivot) {

    List<Integer> l =  new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < left.size(); i++) {
        l.add(left.get(i));
    }

    l.add(pivot);

    for (int i = l.size(); i < right.size(); i++) {
        l.add(right.get(i));
    }
    return l;
}
```

}

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: @CraigOtis Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: I think this is a good chance to learn to use debugger!

Comment: Have you tried debugging your sort method? Often a Stack Overflow when implementing a divide and conquer search algorithm is an off-by-one error where you're calling the `sort()` method with the same arguments repeatedly, often when you get towards a "leaf" of the recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably here:

you choose your pivot as:

```
l.get(0);
```

and then you add your pivot again:

```
int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++
```

as you start from zero!

So change it to start from 1:

```
int i = 1; i < l.size(); i++
```

**EDIT:**
Another mistake is in your `join()` method - you must start from 0 for both arraylists:

```
for (int i = 0; i < right.size(); i++) {
        l.add(right.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Alternatively - use `l.remove(0)` when assigning the pivot, and leave the loop alone. (Unless you don't want to alter the provided `List`.)

Comment: I changed the counter to 1, I get [7, 10] as a result

Comment: @CraigOtis I don't think it's better solution, as remove() will probably have O(n) complexity for the first element..

Answer (score 0):

Consider what happens if you choose the smallest element as your pivot. One of the two sub-lists will be empty, and the other would contain the entire original list, leading to infinite recursion.